# Transform while to for in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, function-definition

I'm beginning with C

I want to change while to for

```
int test(int nb){
    int rv = 0;

 if(nb=1)
     return (1)
 while(rv < nb) {   // change this line 
     if(rv * rv == nb)
         return (rv)
     rv++;
 }
 return (0);
}
```

Can I do :

```
for (int rv=0; rv<nb.length; rv++)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is nb.length?

Comment: "I want to change while to for" Why? If we know the reason, proposing an appropriate solution (maybe a third way) is possible.

Comment: The shown code does not compile. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Both program snippets look very different. Especially there is no `nb.length` in the first snippet.

Comment: for the size but i think doesn't exists

Comment: @zef The for loop is not appropriate for this algorithm.

Comment: use `for (; rv < nb;)` instead of the while statement. You do not need to declare `rv`, as you already declared it at the beginning of the function. Incrementing  `rv` is also done within the loop, so the beforementioned solution should work in your case.

Comment: Note that `if(nb=1)` assigns the value of 1 to `nb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
int test(int nb)
{
  if (nb == 1)    // << changed = to ==
    return (1);   // << added missing ;

  for (int rv = 0; rv < nb; rv++;)   // << modified
  {
    if(rv * rv == nb)
      return (rv);                     // << added missing ;
  }

  return (0);
}
```

But I'm not sure if your original codes is correct in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

So basic syntax of `for` loop is this :-

```
for(initialization; condition; increment){
    // your code
}
```

So you can rewrite your `while` loop as `for` as follows :-

```
for (int rv=0; rv<nb; rv++){
    //rest of code
}
```

The problem with your code is :-

```
for (int rv=0; rv<nb.length; nb++)
//                  ^^ nb is integer type so nb.length doesn't make sense
```

Also incrementing `nb` in your loop will make your loop to iterate forever.

Note :- `if(nb=1)` here, in C, `=` an is assignment operator. To compare you need to use `==`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the condition in your while loop is redundant in terms of using redundant values of `rv`.

```
while(rv < nb) {   // change this line 
     if(rv * rv == nb)
         return (rv)
     rv++;
 }
```

You could rewrite your loop like

```
while ( rv < nb / rv ) ++rv;
```

and after that

```
return rv * rv == nb ? rv : 0;
```

Also it is more logically consistent when the function parameter has an unsigned integer type.

Changing the shown above while loop to a for loop can be done the following way

```
int test( unsigned int n )
{
    unsigned int i = 1;
    
    for ( ; i < n / i; i++ );
    
    return i * i == n ? i : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int rv = 0;rv < nb;rv++) {
```

and remove `rv++;`